# Xcode NSManagedObject subclass auto-generation to overwrite existing files in separate groups

Tags: xcode, core-data, editor, nsmanagedobject

I am using CoreData and the xcdatamodeld editor with great happiness, but when I go to create NSManagedObject subclasses automatically for my entity types, the file placement options seem horribly inflexible.

1. I have to choose a single folder to place all new files
2. New files get re-added to the project at the top level (not in any logical groups)

I have my groups & folders set up to mirror each other, additionally I keep separate groups within my "models" folder for each NSManagedObject subclass (because CoreData creates 2 files for each and it just gets cluttered otherwise).

Problem 1 means that in this situation, I have to generate the files 1 at a time, choosing each subfolder manually. Problem 2 is just an added layer of convenience that I feel like should be avoidable.

It seems like it would be sensible for an option to "overwrite any such existing files in place, wherever they are located & whatever groups they may be in" -- so sensible, in fact, I may just be overlooking the command. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not overlooking any command. Xcode has a different idea of how to organize things than you do. For problem 1, that's just how it is. Xcode won't attempt to locate existing files in your project when re-generating them. Maybe it should, but that's not how it's designed right now.

Comment: if I were to keep all the files in one folder, but the groups still separate (pointing to the same folder), would it solve #2 you think? Problem 2 causes Xcode to think there are duplicate definitions (even though they come from the same source) because they appear twice in the project hierarchy.

Comment: It should, and since you'd be adding the new versions in the same folder, Xcode would at least notice that you're replacing files.